# Generate ordered sql lines to sort them again

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-insert

I'm working on a sort algorithm and want to provide performance for it, so I want to check files before sorting and after sorting. I tried to create sorted files to test the algorithm but it didn't work. What I mean for example this line I want to be for example the numbered id.

```
create table genre (id int, name char(50));

insert into genre (id, name) values (1,'Adventure');
insert into genre (id, name) values (2,'Animation');
insert into genre (id, name) values (3,'Children');
insert into genre (id, name) values (4,'Comedy');
insert into genre (id, name) values (5,'Fantasy');
insert into genre (id, name) values (6,'Romance');
insert into genre (id, name) values (7,'Drama');
```

The problem is that I want to make about a million rows to try it. Is there a way to write query the same but sorted?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. If you want the id column to be auto-populated with a unique number then you can probably do that in your table definition - but how would be dependent on the precise DBMS you are using. However, if you are trying to create sorted records in a table then you should be aware that there is no concept of row order in relational databases

Comment: Ich will die Datei haben, wie der Code oben steht. Es ist egal, welche Spalte sortiert ist, aber muss mind. eine Spalte sortiert, damit ich sie im DBMS testen kann.

Comment: and you’ve replied in German because…?